# Cant link a style.css inside codeigniter view

Tags: php

I am trying to link a css style file from my codeigniter application view. But when i try to access that path "application/views/public/style.css" it says- Access forbidden! Because directory access is prevented by default on codeigniter. Now tell me how can i link that style.css file then? Any idea?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="application/views/public/style.css">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create new directory called `css` in root and move your `style.css` inside the directory

```
/application
/system
/css/style.css
```

now call like following

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?= base_url('css/style.css');?>">
```